# How to create multiple proxies?

Tags: proxy

I need to create around 1000 proxies, in 1 Ubuntu VM. Any method? I need it fast, because is for twitch viewbots.

Comment: Do you know how to create _one_ proxy?

Comment: Yes, I know. With squid

Answer (score -1):

try proxychains i think there's no proxy limit.

Comment: Please do add some details to explain *how* to do what you are suggesting